# Best way to communicate between two programmes (VB.NET)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Afternoon,

I'm looking for some advice on a project I am working on.

Presently I have 2 Console Applications (That run 2 separate API's one for the phone system ACD and one of the Call Recorder).

These churn through traffic and store information in a database ready for a client application (Windows Form) to obtain and use.

At present I am storing the information in a SQL Table and using calls to and from the SQL database in both the Console Applications and Windows Form application.

Is this best practice? In my experience under load the SQL Server could slow down and I don't like the idea of relying on DB requests to send the information back.

Is there a better way I could communicate between my Console Applications and my WIndows Form? I was potentially thinking that TCP messages from one to the other on a port would work and then use the Windows Form to use the 'stream' to perform its actions rather than getting the information from the database.

The reason being is ideally I'd like to have the 'database' as stored within memory for quicker retrieval than using the SQL DB.

Any and all advice is fully appreciated. Please give me an explanation as to why your suggestion is efficient as I would like to learn from this rather than just 'do'

Many Thanks!

James

Comment: Is this session type data? or actual data that needs to be stored and kept safe in case of power loss, etc.   When you are talking about load causing the server to slow down, is this due to amount of data being read, written? number of requests?  This question is vague.

Comment: Hi @KevinCook 

It is session type data, essentially it holds the CallID of the call they are currently on so that it can fire off events to the Call Recorder server via API. It doesn't need to be kept indefinitely. 

If we suffered a powerloss the phones would go anyway. 

In terms of load on the SQL it is used by our bespoke software so there is a lot of read, writes and requests on there in general anyway.

We only have 2 SQL Servers 1 at this office and 1 at the other. I'm assuming TCP is the way to go really?

J

Comment: Rather than writing a lot of plumbing between apps, maybe think about calling a centralized service that keeps track of the workstation/callId?

Comment: I have a similar need (master app -> start slave app's and serve/control the slave apps from  master app in a very performant way). I thought of windows messaging or TCP/IP but not yet found really useful information's. How have you solved your goal?